# How to return value from function called inside class

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I am trying to display a loader when the user clicks on the Export button. I have created a separate class which does this export functionality.

This is the code I have tried.

My problem is that the loader is set to true but I am not sure how to set it to false after export is done.

### HTML

```
<app-loader [showLoader]="showLoader"></app-loader>
```

### ts

```
import { csvExport } from '../../classes/csvExport';

export class DashboardSpaComponent implements OnInit {
    public csvExport: csvExport = new csvExport();

    // LOADER FLAG
    public showLoader: boolean = false;

    downloadPDF() {
        this.showLoader = true;
        //call class
        this.csvExport.download();

    }
}
```

### csvExport.ts

```
export class CsvExport {
    download() {
        // code here to do export 
    }
}
```

Comment: make download function asynchronous using  observable  or promise

Comment: @Madhawa, yes I did some research that tells me about promise. But I don't know how to implement it here

Comment: basically you have to make your download function asynchronous.so when the download is complete  you resolve it .from the  downloadPDF function you can do something when it's completed using `this.csvExport.download().then(()=>{this.showLoader = false;})` .here is a angular example with promises https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-promise-observable-example

Comment: I am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a Promise like this.

```
export class CsvExport {
    download() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           // code here to do export
           // on completion call this. resolve()
        }) 
    }
}
```

And use download function like this

```
this.csvExport.download().then(()=>{
    this.showLoader = false;
})
```

`.then` is called when the promise is resolved (The resolve function is called) 
You can understand more from [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/promises-in-javascript-explained-277b98850de)

Comment: Inside download() i have other function inside function being called. so how ca I use this return new Promise?

Comment: you can add all function calls inside Promise and in the last, call resolve()

Comment: return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.generateCSV("");
            resolve();
        }) I did like following. I have some massive data to export. with this its not working Pls help

Comment: either return promise from `generateCSV` or pass resolve function to `generateCSV` and call it inside `generateCSV` after completion

Comment: Yes, I tried this resturn promise inside generateCSV() but this gives me ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: `.then` will only work on a Promise, so you might be not returning a Promise in the function you are using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192700/discussion-between-nas-and-zaidrehman).